# Setting Default Security Protocol

Tags: vb.net, ssl, payment-gateway, authorize.net, tls1.2

I am integrating on a website with Authorize.net, using AIM. Now I have been testing on my pc and so far the transactions went through and got a response. However, when I pushed my changes online to the server, I am having issues. The response string is being returned empty. I have checked the admin interface and the transactions that occur when I get this issue are not listed.

**UPDATE**

It looks like that by default that the SecurityProtocol was using TLS1.0/SSL3. Now once I did this `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` . The transaction was received

Is there a way to change the default setting of the servicepointmanager to have the value to tls 1.2 so that I do not have to set it?

If i do have to program it, where would it be best to set it? Would it be In application start in global asax,  or each time the request is made?

Comment: Have you tried a simplified version of the code to help now down the potential culprits?

Comment: @JohnConde After much tinkering, I was able to resolve part of my solution, but have different question now. I modified question to something else.